# database query with limit and order_by in django

Tags: python, django, error-handling

i want to display database in table using limit 5 and order_by, whenever i use this query than it show the detail in the table with limit 5 but the list is not in ascending order.

views.py :-

```
def applicationvalues(request):
    gettablevalues = applicationform.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
    getinterviewvalues = interview.objects.all()
    getjobvalues = jobs.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('registration/tableview.html', {'gettablevalues': gettablevalues, 'getinterviewvalues': getinterviewvalues, 'getjobvalues': getjobvalues})
```

Comment: You probably want to use `id` instead of `-id`?

Comment: Ascending order on what field. If you want them to be ordered by any other field instead of id you should use that field name as argument in `order_by` instead of `id`. But @alecxe is right if you want from smallest to biggest lose the `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
gettablevalues = applicationform.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
```

putting `-` before the field sorts it in descending order. I would also have thought that it would be sorted by id in ascending order by default (unless you've overridden that on the model).